# What is the best way to organize Selenium tests with PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, phpunit

I am getting started with writing front-end tests for my project, and I would like to know the best way to organize my selenium test cases.

Should I make a separate suite for each section of the site? Or do I need to group them by acceptance tests (integration), ui verification, and browser compatibility suites?

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I prefer separate suite for each section of the site.

As you are using PHPUnit if you want to run tests parallel then you have to make one classes for one thread.

If you are using the section of site then you will have no Dependencies of one section of site with other. So that you can run the tests in parallel.

Create Section wise library and Suite so that you can run suites in Parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Bromine is a very good way to organize test cases. No need to use suites anymore.You can drag and drop test cases that you need and organize them in a way you want.